# Python to_datetime doesn't show the date in day/months(decimal) format

Tags: python, pandas, statistics

I am learning python by myself and I have the following problem.

First of all the file.csv that I am working on can be accessed here

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1vo5oqrwi0jhcrn/2013_ACCIDENTS_TIPUS_GU_BCN_2013.csv?dl=0

I want to collect my data according to the date and for this I am using "groupby" function. When I run my program in order to get the mean I get "nan". I think that the problem is related to the pd.to_datetime because the new column 'Date' has 0 value. I would appreciate any help you can provide.

Many thanks in advance!

This is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import datetime as dt


data = pd.read_csv("Desktop/2013_ACCIDENTS_TIPUS_GU_BCN_2013.csv")

print(data)

data["Date"] = data[u'Dia de mes'].apply(lambda x: str(x)) + '-' + data[u'Mes de any'].apply(lambda x: str(x))
               
data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"], format = '%d%m', errors = 'coerce')
data.info()
data
accidents = data.groupby(['Date']).size()
print(accidents)
print(accidents.mean())
```

This is the output:

```
N�mero d'expedient Codi districte  ... Coordenada UTM (Y) Coordenada UTM (X)
0            2013S009145             10  ...         4585368,61          432116,29
1            2013S006244             10  ...         4585265,29          432053,62
2            2013S000511             10  ...         4585305,49          432014,19
3            2013S009354             10  ...         4585434,72          431625,93
4            2013S001212             10  ...         4585250,74          431554,85
...                  ...            ...  ...                ...                ...
10034        2013S008522              9  ...         4588380,51          433851,83
10035        2013S005935              9  ...         4588457,97          433753,46
10036        2013S004640              9  ...         4587839,29          433957,61
10037        2013S003063              9  ...         4588028,25          433629,35
10038        2013S006183              9  ...         4588430,86          433021,42

[10039 rows x 20 columns]
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 10039 entries, 0 to 10038
Data columns (total 21 columns):
 #   Column                     Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------                     --------------  -----
 0   N�mero d'expedient         10039 non-null  object
 1   Codi districte             10039 non-null  object
 2   Nom districte              10039 non-null  object
 3   Codi barri                 10039 non-null  object
 4   Nom barri                  10039 non-null  object
 5   Codi carrer                10039 non-null  object
 6   Nom carrer                 10039 non-null  object
 7   Num postal caption         10039 non-null  object
 8   Descripci� dia setmana     10039 non-null  object
 9   Dia setmana                10039 non-null  object
 10  Descripci� tipus dia       10039 non-null  object
 11  NK Any                     10039 non-null  int64
 12  Mes de any                 10039 non-null  int64
 13  Nom mes                    10039 non-null  object
 14  Dia de mes                 10039 non-null  int64
 15  Hora de dia                10039 non-null  int64
 16  Descripci� torn            10039 non-null  object
 17  Descripci� tipus accident  10039 non-null  object
 18  Coordenada UTM (Y)         10039 non-null  object
 19  Coordenada UTM (X)         10039 non-null  object
 20  Date                       0 non-null      datetime64[ns]
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), int64(4), object(16)
memory usage: 1.6+ MB
Series([], dtype: int64)
nan
```

Comment: I'm going to guess that your months and days are not zero padded.  `%m%d` requires something like `01-02`, not `1-2`.  Perhaps try  using zfill on your month and day when joining them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I try to use the function zfill() (`data["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(data["Date"].astype(str).str.zfill(1), format = '%d%m', errors = 'coerce')`)but still doesn't work. I try also to change format in the following way '%-d%-m but again doesn't work. Any further help would be appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it.  You need to zfill the days and month, and use the `dayfirst` parameter.  I'm assuming `NK Any` is the year.  If it is not you can remove it and change the format to simply `%d-%m`

```
pd.to_datetime(df['Dia de mes'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + '-' + df['Mes de any'].astype(str).str.zfill(2) + '-' + df['NK Any'].astype(str), dayfirst=True, format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Chris. This solved my problem.